# Django - Retieve Data from Reservation Form and Display back to User

Tags: python, django, database, for-loop, crud

Trying to pull data from my Database and display it back to the user so they can edit/delete it for full CRUD functionality. At the moment when i iterate through the reservations it comes back empty. Below is the relevent code:

Models.py file:

```
class Reservations(models.Model):


    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phoneNumberRegex], max_length=16, 
unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(choices=time_options, default="12pm", max_length=10)
    number_of_party = models.IntegerField(choices=party_size, default=1)
    reservation_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, 
editable=False, max_length=15)
```

Then the forms.py file:

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservations
        fields = ['name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'date', 'time', 'number_of_party']
        widgets = {
            'date': DatePickerInput(format='%d-%m-%Y'),
        }
```

Views.py:

```
class RetrieveReservationView(ListView):
    model = Reservations
```

Path in the Urls.py file:

```
path('retrieve/<slug:pk>/', RetrieveReservationView.as_view(), name="retrieve_reservation"),
```

And Finally the Html file associated with it:

```
<ul>
    <!-- Iterate over reservations list -->
    {% for reservation in reservations %}
    <!-- Display Objects -->
    <li>{{ reservation.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ reservation.phone_number }}</li>
    <li>{{ reservation.email }}</li>
    <li>{{ reservation.date }}</li>
    <li>{{ reservation.time }}</li>
    <li>{{ reservation.number_of_party }}</li>

    <hr/>
    <!-- If object_list is empty  -->
    {% empty %}
    <li>No Reservation have been made</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

At the moment i just keep getting back "No Reservation has been made" but i have two/three in the database for the user logged in.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
New to Django.

Cheers

Comment: Could you try `for reservation in object_list` in the html. [like mentioned in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

Comment: Tried that and also for reservations in object_list and still the same result. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Is your html file called `reservations_list.html`?

Comment: The html file is actually called reservations_account as i want to render the reservation there after they've signed in and then have an edit/delete off that page

Comment: In that case i think you should do the following in urls.py: `RetrieveReservationView.as_view(template_name="reservations_account.html")`

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the help/suggestions

Comment: Still no joy. Appreciate all your suggestions though Ruud

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you have reservations in the db? what happens why you run `python ./manage.py shell` and then `Reservations.objects.all()`? Does it return reservations?

Comment: It returns "Reservations" is not defined. If i access the admin panel then i can see the reservations on the database there

Comment: Adding the following to my ReservationFormView I'm able to print the reservations to the terminal:                        def get(self, request):
        r = Reservations.objects.all()
        print(r)
        return render(request, self.template_name, { 'object_list': r})